# Integer to UUID conversion using padded 0's

Tags: java, mysql, cassandra, uuid, nosql

I have a question regarding UUID generation.

Typically, when I'm generating a UUID I will use a random or time based generation method.

HOWEVER, I'm migrating legacy data from MySQL over to a C* datastore and I need to change the legacy (auto-incrementing) integer IDs to UUIDS.  Instead of creating another denormalized table with the legacy integer IDs as the primary key and all the data duplicated, I was wondering what folks thought about padding 0's onto the front of the integer ID to form a UUID.  Example below.

*Something important to note is that the legacy IDs highest values will never top 1 million, so overflow isn't really an issue.

The idea would look like this:

Legacy ID: 123456    --->    UUID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000123456

This would be done using some string concats and the UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000123456" method.

Does this seem like a bad pattern to anyone?  I'm not a huge fan of the idea, gives me a bad taste in my mouth, but I don't have a technical reason for why haha.

As far as collisions go, the probability of a collision occurring is still ridiculously low.  So I'm not worried about increasing collisions.  I suppose it just seems like bad practice to me, that its "too easy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go in a different direction from doanduyhai's answer.

In order to maintain data consistency, we decided to fully de-normalize the data and create another table in C* that is keyed on our legacy IDs.  When migrating the objects from our legacy into C*, they are assigned a new randomly generated UUID, which will be their new primary ID for the future.  The legacy IDs will be kept around until such a time that we decide they are no longer needed.  Upon that time, we can cleanly drop the legacy ID table and be done with them.

This solution allowed for a cleaner break from our legacy ID system in the future, and allowed us to prevent the use of strange custom made UUIDs.  I also wasn't a huge fan of having the ID field as a blob type that could have multiple types of data stored in it since, in the future, we plan on only wanting UUIDs to be there.

Answer (score 2):

We faced the same kind of issue before when migrating from Oracle with ids generated by sequence to Cassandra with generated UUIDs.

We had to design a type to both support old data coming from Oracle with type `long` and new data with `uuid`.

The obvious solution is to use type `blob` to store the id. A blob can encode a `long` or an `uuid`.

This solution only works for partition key because you query them using `=`. It won't work for clustering column using operators like `>` or `<` because we need an ordering on their value.

There was a small objection at that time, which was using a `blob` to store the id makes it opaque to user, for example in **cqlsh** when you're doing a SELECT and you need to provide the id, how would you make a blob ?

Fortunately, the native functions of CQL `bigIntAsBlob()`, `blobAsBigInt()`, `uuidAsBlob()` and `blobAsUUID()` come in very handy.